# Struts2 - Access request object inside action's execute method

Tags: java, struts2, request

Is it possible to access the `request` object inside an struts2 action's `execute()` method?

My requirement is to get some parameter value from the request scope which is being sent by some third party site, using URL redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the RequestAware interface is what you want.